# __utma & __utmz cookies are not getting set in browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
   ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Using this code, __utma & __utmz cookies are not getting set in browser. Code is appended in body.

Answer (score 0):

__utma and __utmz cookies don't exist on the current version of the google analytics api (analytics.js aka Universal Analytics).

This is perfectly normal instead it uses a cookie called _ga by default.

See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage